# Typescript: How to make a type that is the keys of an interface but only the keys that are strings

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have this interface

```js
interface MyInterface {
   val1: string
   val2: string
   val3: number
   val4: string
   val5: Date
}
```

I want to make a type that is the keys of the MyInterface but only the keys that are strings:

```js
type myType = keyof MyInterface //where key === typeof 'string'
// myType: 'val1' | 'val2' | 'val4'
```

How could I do something like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to preserve only specif keys and then do a keyof on the resulting type

```
type myType = keyof {
    [P in keyof MyInterface as MyInterface[P] extends string ? P: never]: any
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=16&pln=2&pc=16#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlSA3OAGwEYAuZAZzClAHMTyqAmeplkdqWQVKAZnogArgFsARtA7CqAFl7M2ikQFZ6AETiQiAXyJEw6AA4pp6ACqWUAXmQBrCOgD2MQouQBtAAVkUFd3LzQsHFhEFDgGCOxIaKRAgF1kCAAPSBAAE3i+NmQAfmQAiQgyaFT6OBB0YyA)

You could also make it generic

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V? P: never]: any
}

type myType = KeyOfType<MyInterface, string>
type myType2 = KeyOfType<MyInterface, number>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlSA3OAGwEYAuZAZzClAHMTyqAmeplkdqWQVKAZnogArgFsARtA7CqAFl7M2ikQFZ6AETiQiAXyJEw6AA4oA0hHQB5GABVLEADxOANMgBqAPmQAXmQAazsAexhCRWQAbQAFZFBQiKinZDgGZCcEgF1kCAAPSBAAEyyfAH5keIkIMmhc+jgQdGNTcytkaXQXLuDbB2dXNwxsSFhECG8+Nj8zV27e1y4g5EHHPvcxnEmkbyk5aD8gA)

The `as` clause of a mapped type allows us to manipulate the name of the key. If the key is mapped to `never` the key gets removed from the resulting type. You can find more info in this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

Comment: The "old" way would also work   `type KeyOfType<T, V> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends V ? P: never }[keyof T]`

Comment: @AlekseyL. yeah . it would . But the new way is way more readable IMO