# Transform array of objects to a map indexed by object key

Tags: arrays, typescript, hashmap

I'm trying to convert an array of object to a map, indexed by an attribue value of the Object in `typescript` **4.1.5**

Furthermore I want only the attributes of a certain type (here `string`)

A very similar question have been asked in `javascript` here : [Convert object array to hash map, indexed by an attribute value of the Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264956/convert-object-array-to-hash-map-indexed-by-an-attribute-value-of-the-object)

```
type Foo = {
        a : string
        b : number
}

const foos: Foo[] = []
// should only propose to index by 'a'
const foos_indexed_by_a = indexArrayByKey(foos, 'a')

function indexArrayByKey<T> (array: T[], key: Extract<keyof T, string>): Map<string, T> {
        return array.reduce((map, obj) => map.set(obj[key], obj), new Map<string, T>())
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFL2sEMoBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOaY7YBGhUVArgLaMRnoC+6dAGM4VUlABmCYkXhwA2gF1kUJegD06kgAs4bADYATKKP0goYMnDBxi0YImqGIADyiNzAclyfho8VK2APpOrhCGQR5B+CihLgCCZGS4IABCIADSECAAFIHEADRQ3p4AlIISbFRCwBSiUHGJyWmZ2QA8ACoAfFA5uEkpRB1KRQDW2UQAoi7kuDVt4yBwElAdRaSUtF2lRACyuGBtG9Q0Rd1o9AxQZBDAbGRUUP3NAHQ3hmxCEDk5HAdFcEYACtSsgen8wC87MAcoCgfJFso4aUilQIAB3KD7Q7HWhnLo5UrlPhAA)

For now I can't access property `key` of `obj` (compilation failure)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter the keys based on which have a string value you can't use `Extarct` that filters the keys which are strings (not number or symbol). You can use `KeyOfType` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008324/125734)

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V? P: never]: any
}
function indexArrayByKey<T, K extends KeyOfType<T, string>> (array: T[], key: K): Map<T[K], T> {
        return array.reduce((map, obj) => map.set(obj[key], obj), new Map<T[K], T>())
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFL2sEMoBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOaY7YBGhUVArgLaMRnoC+6dAGM4VUlABmCYkXhwA2gF1kUJegD06kgAs4bADYATKKP0goYMnDBxi0YImqGIADyiNzAclyfho8VK2APpOrhCGQR5B+CihLgCCZGS4IABCIADSECAAFIHEADRQ3p4AlOigkFBZIADyEgAq4BAAPA1FAGoAfCoA1tlwEmj0WPIAClDUUP0gg1ANULjE8+PKrsAQVIbLHQD8UGNEVBAAbjyKRLhUIPzoEmxUQsAUopNbronJaZnZbUUZUHWm221Wy9SakD+JHI1BoXR6OVwSRSRAaSiKMyIGVKRAAsrgwG15BlFEUGj0MAxsGQIMA2GQqItkSAAHQ0wxsIQQHI5DgEopwRgAK1KyB6fLALLswBygqF8hmpJMwtKRWOAHcoPjCWiSWSujlSuUBEA)

We use `T[K]` instead of `string` because `T[K]` could also be a subtype of `string` so TS would complain at `string`, but for cases this will work well.

Comment: I think you were right my answer was missing the point. The question clearly says *"indexed by an attribue value of the Object"*. *sigh* :-)

Comment: Thanks your answer works really well in typescript v4.5.4 but not in the one I'm using v4.1.5. I should have specified it sorry. Do you have a solution for it ?

Comment: @Nainpo you can just swap out the definition of `KeyOfType` with the older one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419176/how-to-get-a-subset-of-keyof-t-whose-value-tk-are-callable-functions-in-typ  The rest should work.

Comment: Playground link for older compatible version: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFL2sEMoBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOaY7YBGhUVArgLaMRnoC+6dAGM4VUlABmCYkXhwA2gF1kUJegD06kgAs4bADYATKKP0goYMnDBxi0YImqGIADyiNzAclyfho8VK2APpOrhCGQR5B+CihLgCCZGS4IABCIADSECAAFIHEADRQ3p4AlOigkFBZIADyEgAq4BAAPA1FAKoAfCqo8gAKUNRQANbZcBJQDYpEDQPKrsAQVIbEUB1QAPxQ-URUEABuPHzyYyATU4roEmxUQsAUokMrronJaZnZbUUZUIvLq2q2XqTUg3xI5GoNC6PRyuCSKVmSiKZyIGVKRAAsrgwG15BlFEUGj0MAxsGQIMA2GQqFB4e8AHQUwxsIQQHI5Dg4opwRgAK1KyB6XLADLswByvL5p2yhJM-NKRX2AHcoNjcXMCUSujlSuUBEA

Comment: Thanks for the new definition it's ok ! :)