# Typescript type that only allows keys whose fields are strings

Tags: typescript, types

I have looked at similar questions, but they stop one step short of what I need.
For example solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008324/4363604) doesn't work when I try to use it in a function:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlSA3OAGwEYAuZAZzClAHMTyqAmeplkdqWQVKAZnogArgFsARtA7CqAFl7M2ikQFZ6AETiQiAXyJEw6AA4oA0hHQB5GABVLEADxOANMgBqAPmQAXmQAazsAexhCRWQAbQAFZFBQiKinZDgGZCcEgF1kCAAPSBAAEyyfAH5keIkIMmhc+jgQdGNTcytkaXQXLuDbB2dXNwxsSFhECG8+Nj8zV27e1y4g5EHHPvcxnEmkbyk5aHmiGEkQBDBgcJBkGC4PAIAKYEhpei8U9HoN4asPTwAZXUAj8AEo1PxWNEhMgoBAwJIoLdXhBpLEwuh8plGCDWABuYxAA)

What I need is a function, which takes item T, and a key of T such that the compiler knows the key always refers to a string field, and so the return type of item[key] is string:

```
function f2<T> (item: T, key: StringOnlyKeys<T>): string {
    return item[key] as string;
}
```

**This doesn't compile in the generic case, see [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#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)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it works:

```
function f2<T extends Record<any, any>>(item: T, key: StringOnlyKeys<T>): string {
    return item[key];
}
```

I'm not 100% sure why, but my guess is that TypeScript won't implicitly restrict generic type parameters. So, if you use an unrestricted `<T>`, that could be a `number` (for instance), and rather than saying *"ah, well that means this function can't possibly be called with a `number`"*, instead the compiler says *"I have no idea what `StringOnlyKeys<number>` means, so anything involving it must be `any`"*.